# Laravel - [DB::connection(...)->select(...)] Funciona em um Job, mas não funciona em outro!

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

**Olá**, estou com um problema que parece impossível de se resolver.

Na minha aplicação Laravel 6.X, tenho um relatório que realiza extrações do banco de dados para arquivos Excel, este relatório possui duas versões de extração:

• Atividades Valorizadas (Funcional)

• Atividades por Período (Não Funcional)

Os dois módulos de extração tem uma estrutura similar, porém, só o Job AtividadeValorizada.php funciona. percebi que a variável (array) ***$rows*** só acaba sendo preenchida no job de atividades valorizadas, por algum motivo desconhecido no outro job essa variável não está sendo preenchida

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers\Administrativo\Pit\Relatorio\Atividade;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use App\Models\Metodo\Pit\PitTipoAtividades;

use App\Http\Requests\Pit\Relatorios\RelatorioAtividadeRequest;

use App\Jobs\Pit\Relatorios\Atividades\AtividadeValorizada;
use App\Jobs\Pit\Relatorios\Atividades\AtividadePorPeriodo;

class AtividadeController extends Controller{

    public function __construct() {

        $this->middleware('auth:administrativo');
    }

    public function index() {

        $tipoatividades = PitTipoAtividades::all();

        return view('administrativo.pit.relatorio.atividades.index')->with([
            'acao' => 'Adicionar',
            'tipoatividades' => $tipoatividades,
            'ind_meses' => dominios('IND_MESES')
        ]);
    }

    public function getAtividadeValorizado(RelatorioAtividadeRequest $request){

        try {
            AtividadeValorizada::dispatchNow($request->all());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }

        return response()->json(
            route('admin.metodo.pit.efetivo.relatorio.atividade.index')
        );
    }

    public function getAtividadePeriodoInformado(RelatorioAtividadeRequest $request){

        try {
            AtividadePorPeriodo::dispatchNow($request->all());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }

        return response()->json(
            route('admin.metodo.pit.efetivo.relatorio.atividade.index')
        );
    }
}
```

**Job Atividades Valorizadas**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Pit\Relatorios\Atividades;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use App\Exports\Excel\CollectionExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

use DB;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use App\Models\Metodo\Pit\PitAtividadeExport;

use Monolog\Formatter\HtmlFormatter;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Processor\MemoryUsageProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\ProcessIdProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor;

class AtividadeValorizada implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    protected $request;
    public $timeout = 120; //O número de segundos que o trabalho pode ser executado antes do tempo limite
    public $tries = 5; //O número de vezes que o trabalho pode ser tentado.

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $request){
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->request['mes_referencia'] = str_pad($this->request['mes_referencia'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    public function handle(){

        try{
            $countAtividadeExport = PitAtividadeExport::whereRaw("ANO_MES = to_char(".$this->request['ano_letivo'].",'fm0000')||to_char(".$this->request['mes_referencia'].",'fm00')")->count();
            $mesReferencia = '';
            foreach(dominios('IND_MESES') as $meses){
                if($meses['val_dominio_item'] == $this->request['mes_referencia']){
                    $mesReferencia = $meses['dsc_dominio_item'];
                }
            }

            $rows = array();
            $heards = null;

            if($countAtividadeExport > 0 && isset($this->request['base_atual'])) {
                $rows = DB::connection('metodo_hml')->select(" SELECT
                        p.cod_pessoa,
                        f.nom_func,
                        p.cod_ativde,
                        t.nom_ativde,
                        to_char(p.dat_inicio,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inicio,
                        to_char(p.dat_termino,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_termino,
                        x.cod_emp,
                        x.cod_ccusto
                    FROM
                        pit_atividade p,
                        vwm_populis_func f,
                        pit_tp_atividade t,
                        g_centro_custo x,
                        g_pessoa a,
                        pit_tp_categoria_docente s
                    WHERE
                        p.cod_pessoa = f.cod_pessoa
                        AND  p.cod_ativde = t.cod_ativde
                        AND  p.cod_ativde = DECODE(:cod_atividade,NULL,p.cod_ativde,:cod_atividade)
                        AND  p.cod_pessoa = a.cod_pessoa
                        AND  a.cod_categoria = s.cod_categoria (+)
                        AND  a.cod_sub_categoria = s.cod_sub_categoria (+)
                        AND  p.cod_emp = x.cod_emp
                        AND  p.cod_ccusto = x.cod_ccusto
                        AND  s.ind_status = 'A'
                        AND  p.ind_status = 'A'
                        AND  TO_CHAR(:ano_letivo,'fm0000') || TO_CHAR(:mes_referencia,'fm00') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(p.dat_inicio,'rrrrmm') AND TO_CHAR(p.dat_termino,'rrrrmm')
                        AND  nvl(TO_CHAR(f.dat_demissao,'yyyymm'),999999) >= TO_CHAR(:ano_letivo,'fm0000') || TO_CHAR(:mes_referencia,'fm00')
                        AND  TO_CHAR(:ano_letivo,'fm0000') || TO_CHAR(:mes_referencia,'fm00') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(p.dat_inicio,'rrrrmm') AND TO_CHAR(p.dat_termino,'rrrrmm')
                    ORDER BY
                        p.cod_pessoa,
                        p.dat_inicio DESC,
                        p.dat_termino DESC",
                    [
                        'ano_letivo'     => $this->request['ano_letivo'],
                        'mes_referencia' => $this->request['mes_referencia'],
                        'cod_atividade'  => $this->request['tipo_atividade']
                    ]);

                foreach ($rows as $index => $row):
                    if ($row->ind_tp_peridiocidade = 'S') {
                        $horas_sem      = $row->qtd_horas;
                        $horas_men      = $row->qtd_horas * 4.5;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_sem = $horas_sem;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_men = $horas_men;
                    } elseif ($row->ind_tp_peridiocidade = 'Q') {
                        $horas_sem      = $row->qtd_horas / 2;
                        $horas_men      = $row->qtd_horas / 2 * 4.5;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_sem = $horas_sem;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_men = $horas_men;
                    } else {
                        $horas_sem      = $row->qtd_horas / 4.5;
                        $horas_men      = $row->qtd_horas;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_sem = $horas_sem;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_men = $horas_men;

                    }
                    //busca se o docente está afastado

                    $buscaDocenteAfastado = $this->getDocenteAfastado($row->cod_pessoa, $this->request['ano_letivo'], $this->request['mes_referencia']);

                    $rows[$index]->data_inicio_afastamento = $buscaDocenteAfastado[0]->data_inicio_afastamento;
                    $rows[$index]->data_termino_afastamento = $buscaDocenteAfastado[0]->data_termino_afastamento;
                    if ($buscaDocenteAfastado[0]->data_inicio_afastamento != '' && $row->status_docente = 'ATIVO') {
                        $rows[$index]->novo_status_docente  = 'AFASTADO';
                    } else {
                        $rows[$index]->novo_status_docente  = $row->status_docente;
                    }
                    $dataFunQtdDiasMes    = "01-";
                    if(...}

                    $concatInicio         = $dataFunQtdDiasMes.$this->request['mes_referencia'].'-'.$this->request['ano_letivo'];
                    $concatFim            = $dataFunQtdDiasMesFim.$this->request['mes_referencia'].'-'.$this->request['ano_letivo'];
                    $atvd                 = 'ATVD';

                    if ($row->ind_tp_calc <> 'F') {
                        if ($row->ind_tp_peridiocidade = 'S') {
                            $valor = $row->pago_valor * 4.5;
                            $rows[$index]->pago_valor = $valor;
                            $valorPago  = $this->round($row->cod_pessoa,$this->request['ano_letivo'],$this->request['mes_referencia'],"'$concatInicio'","'$concatFim'","'$atvd'");
                            $round  = $row->pago_valor / 30 * $valorPago[0]->round;
                            $rows[$index]->vlr_informado = round($round,2);
                        } elseif ($row->ind_tp_peridiocidade = 'Q') {
                            $valor = $row->pago_valor / 2 * 4.5;
                            $rows[$index]->pago_valor = $valor;
                            $valorPago  = $this->round($row->cod_pessoa,$this->request['ano_letivo'],$this->request['mes_referencia'],"'$concatInicio'","'$concatFim'","'$atvd'");
                            $round  = $row->pago_valor / 30 * $valorPago[0]->round;
                            $rows[$index]->vlr_informado = round($round,2);
                        } else {
                            $valor = $row->pago_valor;
                            $rows[$index]->pago_valor = $valor;
                            $valorPago  = $this->round($row->cod_pessoa,$this->request['ano_letivo'],$this->request['mes_referencia'],"'$concatInicio'","'$concatFim'","'$atvd'");
                            $round  = $row->pago_valor / 30 * $valorPago[0]->round;
                            $rows[$index]->vlr_informado = round($round,2);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $valor = $row->pago_valor;
                        $rows[$index]->pago_valor = $valor;
                        $valorPago  = $this->round($row->cod_pessoa,$this->request['ano_letivo'],$this->request['mes_referencia'],"'$concatInicio'","'$concatFim'","'$atvd'");
                        $round  = $row->pago_valor / 30 * $valorPago[0]->round;
                        $rows[$index]->vlr_informado = round($round,2);

                    }

                    if(!$heards){
                        $heards = array_keys((array)$row);
                    }
                endforeach;

            }elseif($countAtividadeExport > 0 && !isset($this->request['base_atual'])){
                $rows = DB::connection('metodo_hml')->select("
                    SELECT
                        p.cod_pessoa,
                        f.nom_func,
                        p.cod_ativde,
                        t.nom_ativde,
                        to_char(p.dat_inicio,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inicio,
                        to_char(p.dat_termino,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_termino
                    FROM
                        pit_atividade_export     p,
                        pit_funcionario_export   f,
                        pit_tp_atividade_export  t,
                        g_centro_custo           x,
                        g_pessoa_export          a,
                        pit_tp_cat_doc_export    s
                    WHERE   p.cod_pessoa = f.cod_pessoa
                        AND f.ano_mes = p.ano_mes
                        AND p.cod_ativde = t.cod_ativde
                        AND t.ano_mes = p.ano_mes
                        AND p.cod_pessoa = a.cod_pessoa
                        AND a.ano_mes = p.ano_mes
                        AND s.ind_status = 'I'
                        AND p.ind_status = 'A'
                        AND p.cod_emp = x.cod_emp
                        AND p.cod_ccusto = x.cod_ccusto
                        AND a.cod_categoria = s.cod_categoria(+)
                        AND a.cod_sub_categoria = s.cod_sub_categoria(+)
                        --AND s.ano_mes(+) = to_char(:ano_letivo,'fm0000')||to_char(:mes_referencia,'fm00')
                        AND p.cod_ativde = decode(:cod_atividade,null,p.cod_ativde,:cod_atividade)
                        AND p.ano_mes = to_char(:ano_letivo,'fm0000')||to_char(:mes_referencia,'fm00')
                        AND nvl(to_char(f.dat_demissao,'yyyymm'),999999) >= to_char(:ano_letivo,'fm0000')||to_char(:mes_referencia,'fm00')
                        AND to_char(:ano_letivo,'fm0000')||to_char(:mes_referencia,'fm00') BETWEEN to_char(p.dat_inicio,'rrrrmm') AND to_char(p.dat_termino,'rrrrmm')
                    ORDER BY
                        p.cod_pessoa,
                        p.dat_inicio desc,
                        p.dat_termino desc",
                    [
                        'ano_letivo'     => $this->request['ano_letivo'],
                        'mes_referencia' => $this->request['mes_referencia'],
                        'cod_atividade'  => $this->request['tipo_atividade']
                    ]
                );

                foreach ($rows as $index => $row):
                    if ($row->ind_tp_peridiocidade = 'S') {
                        $horas_sem      = $row->qtd_horas;
                        $horas_men      = $row->qtd_horas * 4.5;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_sem = $horas_sem;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_men = $horas_men;
                    } elseif ($row->ind_tp_peridiocidade = 'Q') {
                        $horas_sem      = $row->qtd_horas / 2;
                        $horas_men      = $row->qtd_horas / 2 * 4.5;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_sem = $horas_sem;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_men = $horas_men;
                    } else {
                        $horas_sem      = $row->qtd_horas / 4.5;
                        $horas_men      = $row->qtd_horas;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_sem = $horas_sem;
                        $rows[$index]->horas_men = $horas_men;

                    }
                    //busca se o docente está afastado
                    $buscaDocenteAfastado = $this->getDocenteAfastado($row->cod_pessoa, $this->request['ano_letivo'], $this->request['mes_referencia']);
                    $rows[$index]->data_inicio_afastamento = $buscaDocenteAfastado[0]->data_inicio_afastamento;
                    $rows[$index]->data_termino_afastamento = $buscaDocenteAfastado[0]->data_termino_afastamento;
                    if ($buscaDocenteAfastado[0]->data_inicio_afastamento != '' && $row->status_docente = 'ATIVO') {
                        $rows[$index]->novo_status_docente  = 'AFASTADO';
                    } else {
                        $rows[$index]->novo_status_docente  = $row->status_docente;
                    }
                    $dataFunQtdDiasMes    = "01-";
                    if(...){...}
                    $concatInicio         = $dataFunQtdDiasMes.$this->request['mes_referencia'].'-'.$this->request['ano_letivo'];
                    $concatFim            = $dataFunQtdDiasMesFim.$this->request['mes_referencia'].'-'.$this->request['ano_letivo'];
                    $atvd                 = 'ATVD';
                    if ($row->ind_tp_calc <> 'F') {...}
                    } else {
                        $valor = $row->pago_valor;
                        $rows[$index]->pago_valor = $valor;
                        $valorPago  = $this->round($row->cod_pessoa,$this->request['ano_letivo'],$this->request['mes_referencia'],"'$concatInicio'","'$concatFim'","'$atvd'");
                        $round  = $row->pago_valor / 30 * $valorPago[0]->round;
                        $rows[$index]->vlr_informado = round($round,2);
                    }
                    if(!$heards){
                        $heards = array_keys((array)$row);
                    }
                endforeach;
            }

            if($rows){...}

        }catch(Exception $th) {...}
    }

}
```

**Job Atividades Por Período**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Pit\Relatorios\Atividades;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use App\Exports\Excel\CollectionExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use Monolog\Formatter\HtmlFormatter;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Processor\MemoryUsageProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\ProcessIdProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor;

class AtividadePorPeriodo implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    protected $request;
    public $timeout = 120; //O número de segundos que o trabalho pode ser executado antes do tempo limite
    public $tries = 5; //O número de vezes que o trabalho pode ser tentado.

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct(array $request){
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->request = $request;

        $this->request['data_inicio'] = Carbon::parse($this->request['data_inicio'])->format('d/m/Y');;
        $this->request['data_fim'] = Carbon::parse($this->request['data_fim'])->format('d/m/Y');
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(){

        try{

            $rows = array();
            $heards = array();

            $rows = DB::connection('metodo_hml')->select(" SELECT 
                    A.COD_ATIVDE, INITCAP(NOM_ATIVDE) Atividade,
                    b.cod_ccusto,
                    (SELECT gcc.dsc_ccusto
                     FROM   g_centro_custo gcc 
                     WHERE  gcc.cod_ccusto = b.cod_ccusto) dsc_ccusto,
                    decode(IND_NIVEL_ATIVDE,'T','Turma','C','Curso','Institucional') Nivel_Atividade, 
                    DECODE(IND_TP_CALC, 'F','Valor Fixo','C','Categoria', 'H','Hora Atividade') Tipo_calculo,
                    decode(ind_tp_ativde,1, 'Atividade',2,'Aula',3,'Pesquisa',4,'Extensão') Tipo_atividade,
                    decode(IND_SUP_ADM,'S','Suplementar','A','Administracao') Classificacao_atividade,
                    b.cod_pessoa,
                    f.cod_pessoa_rm, 
                    f.nom_func,
                    to_char(f.dat_demissao,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_demissao,
                    to_char(af.dat_inicio_afast,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inicio_afast,
                    to_char(af.dat_termino_afast,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_termino_afast,
                    to_char(b.dat_inicio,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inicio,
                    to_char(b.dat_termino,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_termino,
                    B.QTD_HORAS, 
                    B.QTD_HOR_REF,  
                    b.vlr_atividade,
                    b.IND_TP_PERIDIOCIDADE,  
                    decode(b.IND_TP_PERIDIOCIDADE,'M','Mensal','Q','Quinzenal','S','Semanal') periodicidade,
                    decode(b.ind_status,'A','Ativa','Inativada') situacao_atividade,
                    b.cod_usuario,
                    u.nom_usuario,
                    decode(b.ind_transacao,'I','Inclusao','U','Alteracao') tipo_transacao,
                    to_char(b.dat_transacao,'dd/mm/rrrr hh24:mi:ss') dat_transacao,
                    b.dsc_atividade,
                    b.dsc_observacao||rat.dsc_observacao dsc_observacao,
                    rat.num_seq_regime_ano_letivo,
                    rat.ind_tp_nivel_ativ_curso,
                    (SELECT DISTINCT b.rv_meaning
                     FROM cg_ref_codes b
                     WHERE UPPER(b.RV_LOW_VALUE) = UPPER(rat.ind_tp_nivel_ativ_curso)
                     AND UPPER(b.rv_domain) = 'TP_NIVEL_ATIV_CURSO') descricao,
                    rat.num_ordem,
                    rat.cod_curso,
                    gc.nom_curso,
                    rat.cod_usuario usuario_rateio,
                    to_char(rat.dat_inclusao,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inclusao_rat,
                    b.cod_atividade,
                    decode(b.cod_modalidade_ensino,'P','Presencial','D','EAD','A','Ambas') modalidade_ensino
                FROM PIT_TP_ATIVIDADE a, 
                     pit_atividade b, 
                     vwm_populis_func f, 
                     pit_mov_afastamento af, 
                     s_usuario u, 
                     PIT_ATIVIDADE_RATEIO RAT, 
                     gc_curso gc
                WHERE a.COD_ATIVDE      = b.cod_ativde
                    AND b.cod_usuario   = u.cod_usuario
                    AND f.cod_pessoa_pk = (SELECT max(f2.cod_pessoa_pk) 
                                           FROM vwm_populis_func f2
                                           WHERE f2.cod_pessoa = f.cod_pessoa)
                    AND f.cod_pessoa_pk = af.cod_pessoa_pk 
                    AND b.cod_atividade = rat.cod_atividade(+)
                    AND b.cod_pessoa    = rat.cod_pessoa(+)
                    AND rat.cod_curso   = gc.cod_curso(+)
                    AND (((trunc( af.dat_inicio_afast) >= :data_inicio) AND 
                        af.dat_termino_afast is null) 
                                    OR
                        af.dat_termino_afast is null)       
                    AND f.cod_pessoa  = b.cod_pessoa
                    AND b.dat_inicio  >= :data_inicio
                    AND b.dat_termino <= :data_termino
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                    A.COD_ATIVDE, INITCAP(NOM_ATIVDE) Atividade,
                    b.cod_ccusto,
                    (SELECT gcc.dsc_ccusto
                     FROM   g_centro_custo gcc 
                     WHERE  gcc.cod_ccusto = b.cod_ccusto) dsc_ccusto,
                    decode(IND_NIVEL_ATIVDE,'T','Turma','C','Curso','Institucional') Nivel_Atividade, 
                    DECODE(IND_TP_CALC, 'F','Valor Fixo','C','Categoria', 'H','Hora Atividade') Tipo_calculo,
                    decode(ind_tp_ativde,1, 'Atividade',2,'Aula',3,'Pesquisa',4,'ExtensÃ£o') Tipo_atividade,
                    decode(IND_SUP_ADM,'S','Suplementar','A','Administracao') Classificacao_atividade,
                    b.cod_pessoa,
                    f.cod_pessoa_rm, 
                    f.nom_func,
                    to_char(f.dat_demissao,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_demissao, 
                    to_char(af.dat_inicio_afast,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inicio_afast,
                    to_char(af.dat_termino_afast,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_termino_afast,  
                    to_char(b.dat_inicio,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inicio,
                    to_char(b.dat_termino,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_termino,
                    B.QTD_HORAS, 
                    B.QTD_HOR_REF,  
                    b.vlr_atividade,
                    b.IND_TP_PERIDIOCIDADE, 
                    decode(b.IND_TP_PERIDIOCIDADE,'M','Mensal','Q','Quinzenal','S','Semanal') periodicidade,
                    decode(b.ind_status,'A','Ativa','Inativada') situacao_atividade,                         
                    b.cod_usuario,
                    u.nom_usuario,
                    decode(b.ind_transacao,'I','Inclusao','U','Alteracao') tipo_transacao,
                    to_char(b.dat_transacao,'dd/mm/rrrr hh24:mi:ss') dat_transacao,
                    b.dsc_atividade,
                    b.dsc_observacao||rat.dsc_observacao dsc_observacao,
                    rat.num_seq_regime_ano_letivo,
                    rat.ind_tp_nivel_ativ_curso,
                    (SELECT DISTINCT b.rv_meaning
                     FROM cg_ref_codes b
                     WHERE UPPER(b.RV_LOW_VALUE) = UPPER(rat.ind_tp_nivel_ativ_curso)
                     AND UPPER(b.rv_domain) = 'TP_NIVEL_ATIV_CURSO') descricao,
                    rat.num_ordem,
                    rat.cod_curso,
                    gc.nom_curso,
                    rat.cod_usuario usuario_rateio,
                    to_char(rat.dat_inclusao,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inclusao_rat,
                    b.cod_atividade,
                    decode(b.cod_modalidade_ensino,'P','Presencial','D','EAD','A','Ambas') modalidade_ensino
                FROM PIT_TP_ATIVIDADE a, 
                     pit_atividade b,
                     vwm_populis_func f,
                     pit_mov_afastamento af,
                     s_usuario u,
                     PIT_ATIVIDADE_RATEIO RAT,
                     gc_curso gc
                WHERE a.COD_ATIVDE      = b.cod_ativde
                    AND f.cod_pessoa    = b.cod_pessoa  
                    AND b.cod_usuario   = u.cod_usuario
                    AND b.cod_atividade = rat.cod_atividade(+)
                    AND b.cod_pessoa    = rat.cod_pessoa(+)
                    AND rat.cod_curso   = gc.cod_curso(+)
                    AND f.cod_pessoa_pk = (SELECT max(f2.cod_pessoa_pk) 
                                           FROM vwm_populis_func f2
                                           WHERE f2.cod_pessoa = f.cod_pessoa)
                    AND f.cod_pessoa_pk =  af.cod_pessoa_pk 
                    AND trunc(af.dat_inicio_afast)  >= :data_inicio
                    AND trunc(nvl(af.dat_termino_afast, sysdate )) <= :data_termino            
                    AND b.dat_inicio    >= :data_inicio
                    AND b.dat_termino   <= :data_termino                
                UNION ALL
                SELECT   
                    A.COD_ATIVDE, INITCAP(NOM_ATIVDE) Atividade,
                    b.cod_ccusto,
                    (SELECT gcc.dsc_ccusto
                     FROM   g_centro_custo gcc 
                     WHERE  gcc.cod_ccusto = b.cod_ccusto) dsc_ccusto,
                    decode(IND_NIVEL_ATIVDE,'T','Turma','C','Curso','Institucional') Nivel_Atividade, 
                    DECODE(IND_TP_CALC, 'F','Valor Fixo','C','Categoria', 'H','Hora Atividade') Tipo_calculo,
                    decode(ind_tp_ativde,1, 'Atividade',2,'Aula',3,'Pesquisa',4,'ExtensÃ£o') Tipo_atividade,
                    decode(IND_SUP_ADM,'S','Suplementar','A','Administracao') Classificacao_atividade,
                    b.cod_pessoa,
                    f.cod_pessoa_rm, 
                    f.nom_func,
                    to_char(f.dat_demissao,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_demissao,
                    null dat_inicio_afast,
                    null dat_termino_afast,
                    to_char(b.dat_inicio,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inicio,
                    to_char(b.dat_termino,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_termino,
                    B.QTD_HORAS,
                    B.QTD_HOR_REF,
                    b.vlr_atividade,
                    b.IND_TP_PERIDIOCIDADE,
                    decode(b.IND_TP_PERIDIOCIDADE,'M','Mensal','Q','Quinzenal','S','Semanal') periodicidade,
                    decode(b.ind_status,'A','Ativa','Inativada') situacao_atividade,
                    b.cod_usuario,
                    u.nom_usuario,
                    decode(b.ind_transacao,'I','Inclusao','U','Alteracao') tipo_transacao,
                    to_char(b.dat_transacao,'dd/mm/rrrr hh24:mi:ss') dat_transacao,
                    b.dsc_atividade,
                    b.dsc_observacao||rat.dsc_observacao dsc_observacao,
                    rat.num_seq_regime_ano_letivo,
                    rat.ind_tp_nivel_ativ_curso,
                    (SELECT DISTINCT b.rv_meaning
                     FROM cg_ref_codes b
                     WHERE UPPER(b.RV_LOW_VALUE) = UPPER(rat.ind_tp_nivel_ativ_curso)
                     AND UPPER(b.rv_domain) = 'TP_NIVEL_ATIV_CURSO') descricao,
                    rat.num_ordem,
                    rat.cod_curso,
                    gc.nom_curso,
                    rat.cod_usuario usuario_rateio,
                    to_char(rat.dat_inclusao,'dd/mm/rrrr') dat_inclusao_rat,
                    b.cod_atividade,
                    decode(b.cod_modalidade_ensino,'P','Presencial','D','EAD','A','Ambas') modalidade_ensino
                FROM PIT_TP_ATIVIDADE a, 
                     pit_atividade b, 
                     vwm_populis_func f, 
                     s_usuario u,
                     PIT_ATIVIDADE_RATEIO RAT, 
                     gc_curso gc
                WHERE a.COD_ATIVDE      =  b.cod_ativde
                    AND f.cod_pessoa    = b.cod_pessoa  
                    AND b.cod_usuario   = u.cod_usuario
                    AND b.cod_atividade = rat.cod_atividade(+)
                    AND b.cod_pessoa    = rat.cod_pessoa(+)
                    AND rat.cod_curso   = gc.cod_curso(+)
                    AND f.cod_pessoa_pk = (SELECT max(f2.cod_pessoa_pk) 
                                           FROM vwm_populis_func f2
                                           WHERE f2.cod_pessoa = f.cod_pessoa)
                    AND 0 = (SELECT count(*) 
                             FROM pit_mov_afastamento f3
                             WHERE f3.cod_pessoa_pk = f.cod_pessoa_pk
                                AND   trunc(f3.dat_inicio_afast) >= :data_inicio
                                AND ( f3.dat_termino_afast IS NULL  or trunc(f3.dat_termino_afast) <= :data_termino))
                    AND  b.dat_inicio  >= :data_inicio
                    AND  b.dat_termino <= :data_termino 
                ORDER BY 7,14,15",
                [
                    'data_inicio'  => $this->request['data_inicio'],
                    'data_termino' => $this->request['data_fim']
                ]);

            foreach ($rows as $index => $row):  
                if(!$heards){
                    $heards = array_keys((array)$row);
                }
            endforeach;

            if($rows){...}

        }catch(Exception $th) {...}
    }

}
```

Comment: Você testou os SQLs diretamente em um cliente de banco de dados para verificar se funcionam? Seu filtro de datas está correto? Me parece que está tentando formatar a entrada para d/m/Y e ao testar com o banco de dados, pode ser que não funcione

Comment: @AdemirMazerJr-Nuno Testei no client Oracle e funcionou sim, tanto com datas no formato (d/m/Y) ou (d-m-Y)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Está resolvido, por algum motivo a query funcionava em client e não funcionava na chamada pela função.

Então resolvi solucionar da seguinte forma. Já que são 3 querys sobre a mesma tabela com dados diferentes, criei 3 views e fiz uma consulta com filtros com base na query original.

**Query nova**

```
$rows = DB::connection(env('DB_CONNECTION_METODO_DEFAULT'))->select("
                SELECT * FROM VW_PIT_TP_ATIVIDADES_1 
                WHERE 
                TO_DATE(dat_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY')  >= TO_DATE(:data_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY')
                AND TO_DATE(dat_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE(:data_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                AND (TO_DATE(dat_inicio_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY')  >= TO_DATE(:data_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY') OR TO_DATE(dat_inicio_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') IS NULL)
                AND (TO_DATE(dat_termino_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE(:data_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') OR TO_DATE(dat_termino_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') IS NULL) 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM VW_PIT_TP_ATIVIDADES_2 
                WHERE 
                TO_DATE(dat_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY')  >= TO_DATE(:data_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY')
                AND TO_DATE(dat_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE(:data_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                AND (TO_DATE(dat_inicio_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY')  >= TO_DATE(:data_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY') OR TO_DATE(dat_inicio_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') IS NULL)
                AND (TO_DATE(dat_termino_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE(:data_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') OR TO_DATE(dat_termino_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') IS NULL)
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT * FROM VW_PIT_TP_ATIVIDADES_3 
                WHERE 
                TO_DATE(dat_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY')  >= TO_DATE(:data_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY')
                AND TO_DATE(dat_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE(:data_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                AND (TO_DATE(dat_inicio_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY')  >= TO_DATE(:data_inicio,'DD/MM/YYYY') OR TO_DATE(dat_inicio_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') IS NULL)
                AND (TO_DATE(dat_termino_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') <= TO_DATE(:data_termino,'DD/MM/YYYY') OR TO_DATE(dat_termino_afast,'DD/MM/YYYY') IS NULL) ",
                [
                    'data_inicio'  => $this->request['data_inicio'],
                    'data_termino' => $this->request['data_fim']
                ]);
```

Comment: Você pode aceitar sua própria resposta para as contabilizações corretas do Stackoverflow que esta pergunta tem uma solução